# Configure additional filename extensions for Gradle CodeNarc plugin

Tags: gradle, groovy, codenarc

I am currently trying to get the CodeNarc plugin for Gradle 8.0.2 to work in my project.

Due to some reasons, the Groovy files have different extensions. At the moment, the plugin only seems to run for the `*.groovy` files.

Let's say I have a `build.gradle` file like this:

```
plugins {
    id 'groovy'
    id 'java'
    id 'codenarc'
}

repository {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.apache.groovy:groovy-all:4.0.10'
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        groovy {
            srcDirs = ['directory1', 'directory2']
        }
    }
}
```

Now I have the following files:

- `directory1/utils.groovy`
- `directory1/something.groovy`
- `directory2/another.myextension`

Running `./gradlew codenarcMain --info` will not print:

```
No matching files found for FileSet with basedir [/home/path/to/project/directory2]
```

Adding

```
codenarcMain {
    include('**/*.myextension', '**/*.groovy')
}
```

does not seem to change anything.

What is the correct approach to register custom extensions for the CodeNarc plugin from within Gradle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to get gradle's in-built `codenarc` plugin recognize an extension other than `.groovy` even after configuring the groovy compiler to recognize the new extension. However, following [an example](https://codenarc.org/codenarc-run-as-a-test.html) in the codenarc website, I was able to achieve this by creating a custom codenarc gradle task based on the [ant codenarc task](https://codenarc.org/codenarc-ant-task.html). This task is configured to process specific source folder(s)(`src/test/groovy` in the example) and files with specific extensions(`.groovy` and `.dummy` in the example).

```
configurations {
    codenarc
}

dependencies {
    String groovyVersion = '3.0.18'

    codenarc group: 'org.codehaus.groovy', name: 'groovy-templates', version: groovyVersion
    codenarc group: 'org.codehaus.groovy', name: 'groovy-xml', version: groovyVersion
    codenarc group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-api', version: '1.7.35'
    codenarc group: 'ch.qos.logback', name: 'logback-classic', version: '1.2.12'
    codenarc group: 'org.codenarc', name: 'CodeNarc', version: '3.2.0'
}

tasks.register('codenarcTest') {
    String reportsFile = 'build/reports/codenarc.html'
    inputs.files(fileTree('src/test/groovy'))
    outputs.file("$projectDir/$reportsFile")

    doLast {
        ant.taskdef(name:'codenarc', 
                    classname:'org.codenarc.ant.CodeNarcTask', 
                    classpath: configurations.codenarc.asPath)
        ant.codenarc(
           ruleSetFiles: 'rulesets/imports.xml,rulesets/unused.xml',
           maxPriority1Violations: 0, maxPriority2Violations: 0,
           maxPriority3Violations: 0,
        ) {
           fileset(dir:'src/test/groovy') {
               include(name: '**/*.groovy')
               include(name: '**/*.dummy')
           }

           report(type:'html') {
               option(name: 'outputFile', value: reportsFile)
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I managed to get it working with these references.